# Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions about finding data?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As the question states, I want to find data about a particular project and I am wondering what the right place is to ask people how they go about searching for it. Would Stack Overflow be it?

Comment: Can you be more specific?, does [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) help?

Comment: @Rob thanks, yes I think that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those kind of questions belong on [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com) who have a [special tag](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) for them. But, like any resource recommendation requests on Stack Exchange, they have [strict quality guidelines](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/284/14011) you should definitely read before posting a data request. Otherwise the question is likely to be downvoted and/or closed.